# Android. Java. Когда я создаю объект класса, получаю OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, объекты, память, outofmemoryerror

На этой активности вылетает OOM.

Я решил последовательно добавлять строки кода, пока не найду место, где вылетает ошибка. Я его нашёл, как исправить?

```
public class MainPageBasicLayout extends AppCompatActivity {

    int layout1BottomItemNum = 0;
    int layout1BottomSize = 0;

    //JSON Fields
    @Expose
    String Layout1Bottom = null;
    @Expose
    ArrayList<String> Layout1BottomContent = new ArrayList<String>(1);
    @Expose
    ArrayList<String> Layout1BottomAppearance = new ArrayList<String>(1);
    @Expose
    String ExitBehavior = " ";


//ВЫЛЕТАЕТ ПРИ СОЗДАНИИ ОБЪЕКТА КЛАССА
    MainPageBasicLayout obj = new MainPageBasicLayout();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        //Get JSON file content

        String json = null;
        try {
            json = new CfgMgr().GetJsonFileContent(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //GSON
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        MainPageBasicLayout obj = gson.fromJson(json, MainPageBasicLayout.class);

        //Prepare GSON objects to GC
        gson = null;
        builder = null;
        json = null;
        System.gc();

    }


    //Exit by pressing BACK
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();

        if (obj.ExitBehavior.equals("NoReq")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.Confirmation);
            dialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.ReallyExit);
            dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
            // Exit Button
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Exit, (dialog, which) -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.exit(0);


            });

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Зацикливание идёт, при создании объекта `MainPageBasicLayout obj` опять создаётся объект и так пока ресурсы не закончатся.

Comment: Отделите данные от UI, в отдельный класс.

Comment: А почему оно зацикливается?

Comment: Потому что во время создания объекта вызывается создание ещё одного объекта (`obj = new MainPageBasicLayout()`), которое в свою очередь вызывает ещё и так до вылета.